# Java server self-signed certificate + client certificate and SSL - connection reset

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpclient, handshake

(I've already asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738397/java-server-selft-signed-certificate-client-certificate-and-ssl-handshake-failu) and it turns out that my client key wasn't getting loaded, but I only got one exception further so I'm posting another question.)

I'm connecting to a web service which was used before successfully, however now they've changed hostname and sent me two .pem files; one is CA, and other is my new client certificate.

(I'm using Java 1.5, Spring + Spring Web Services with Apache httpclient, but I suspect my problem is with certificates, keys and SSL itself.)

I've imported both .pem files, as well as host's .crt which I exported from Firefox into my cacerts. However, I'm obviously doing something wrong since I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Caused by: 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:284)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:396)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:348)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:720)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1025)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:619)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpConnection.onSendAfterWrite(CommonsHttpConnection.java:83)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:547)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:405)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:358)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:304)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:289)
    ...
```

When I turn on SSL logging with System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all"), I see that server certificate is accepted and then this happens after or somewhere during client key exchange:

```
setting up default SSLSocketFactory
use default SunJSSE impl class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
class com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl is loaded
keyStore is : D:\AdriaticaCentral\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AdriaticaCentralOnlineServer\WEB-INF\classes\keystore
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : ypsilonclient
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 103786554737956184369138386227517475430156404603922533481712260490997247291004352385079204978431207687092828117962473600295977103686791448953158848873575487907656378655168840104433047747570602454550203304683174555325033654946526304210710782190667961616217273402229863778090825217190222869236148684215668636483
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Mar 26 13:14:36 CET 2010,
               To: Mon Mar 23 13:14:36 CET 2020]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    94778886 f4ca92c2]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 86 EE 6C 03 20 76 E5 0C   C7 1D E5 44 60 C0 D0 40  ..l. v.....D`..@
0010: 02 96 EE 05 39 31 E8 5A   FE F4 72 7B 9B CC E7 0F  ....91.Z..r.....
0020: 97 E6 41 7E EC E3 65 C5   A2 B0 41 61 93 B4 48 EE  ..A...e...Aa..H.
0030: DE 44 76 94 C1 48 E4 05   96 C2 0A 9B 1C 94 1B 85  .Dv..H..........
0040: 96 9F F3 00 D3 AC B7 95   C5 2C D5 ED 52 FA D7 79  .........,..R..y
0050: A1 10 BB CB A4 BD 30 08   51 71 50 EE DC 60 88 AD  ......0.QqP..`..
0060: 31 6E 88 D9 97 F3 8B 5B   01 B3 80 B2 B2 06 62 FB  1n.....[......b.
0070: DE A4 74 87 D9 2A 2B 2F   AF 31 22 97 4A F6 B8 9F  ..t..*+/.1".J...

]
***
trustStore is: D:\AdriaticaCentral\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AdriaticaCentralOnlineServer\WEB-INF\classes\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Sat Jun 26 02:19:54 CEST 1999 until Wed Jun 26 02:19:54 CEST 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net, OU=enxi.norrisdata.net, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2
  Valid from Fri Mar 26 11:37:00 CET 2010 until Mon Mar 23 11:37:00 CET 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=certificate@trustcenter.de, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA, O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=certificate@trustcenter.de, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA, O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3eb
  Valid from Mon Mar 09 12:59:59 CET 1998 until Sat Jan 01 12:59:59 CET 2011

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x94778886f4ca92c2
  Valid from Fri Mar 26 13:14:36 CET 2010 until Mon Mar 23 13:14:36 CET 2020

[unimportant certificates snipped]

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4cc7eaaa983e71d39310f83d3a899192
  Valid from Mon May 18 02:00:00 CEST 1998 until Wed Aug 02 01:59:59 CEST 2028

init context
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
instantiated an instance of class com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
http-8080-Processor25, setSoTimeout(90000) called
http-8080-Processor25, setSoTimeout(90000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1296423943 bytes = { 233, 32, 138, 106, 31, 235, 174, 62, 53, 252, 155, 255, 248, 43, 255, 58, 99, 70, 232, 17, 220, 98, 42, 40, 101, 157, 26, 113 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
http-8080-Processor25, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1296423943 bytes = { 201, 241, 99, 38, 140, 0, 132, 20, 231, 186, 165, 243, 178, 143, 146, 172, 108, 161, 126, 74, 70, 56, 138, 165, 39, 99, 254, 173 }
Session ID:  {1, 78, 15, 139, 52, 55, 227, 34, 190, 155, 208, 146, 92, 216, 197, 173, 214, 218, 238, 194, 255, 48, 34, 171, 219, 162, 231, 250, 183, 158, 235, 63}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
http-8080-Processor25, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1378
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net, OU=enxi.norrisdata.net, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 105158323961649143261675059370957210288137897982882368398075567460896421730512351351129218695072925445303830065152794594929017968110838209795249871435238567060656353603426816451022832577131638028495007888967083020723809918589055189033188525472465535607293377867184162059586888049098196531889988723950292830313
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Mar 26 11:37:00 CET 2010,
               To: Mon Mar 23 11:37:00 CET 2020]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    02]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 3A F3 91 84 EA B1 CF 28   7B 52 EC 50 34 56 CB A5  :......(.R.P4V..
0010: 22 B2 3C 62 9B 8C 45 30   BE 89 C6 8C D5 CD D0 4C  ".<b..E0.......L
0020: 0A 92 3C AB C6 72 5C 7E   A4 4B 12 B5 3D 90 6F D1  ..<..r\..K..=.o.
0030: 8D 23 8F FE 46 9E D5 15   BA 8D 32 12 79 86 D8 42  .#..F.....2.y..B
0040: A9 AF 95 3A 58 D6 F0 1C   C9 44 B7 AB 78 F8 0E 16  ...:X....D..x...
0050: E5 B1 30 29 56 D5 C1 4F   06 D2 5C 9B 7F 61 22 7D  ..0)V..O..\..a".
0060: 6C EB C5 7C 02 8B D4 3B   3B 66 20 55 72 2D 1B F1  l......;;f Ur-..
0070: 3A 28 3F 10 80 BC 9F 46   DA 0E 8F DC 53 0E 0B 85  :(?....F....S...

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 103786554737956184369138386227517475430156404603922533481712260490997247291004352385079204978431207687092828117962473600295977103686791448953158848873575487907656378655168840104433047747570602454550203304683174555325033654946526304210710782190667961616217273402229863778090825217190222869236148684215668636483
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Mar 26 13:14:36 CET 2010,
               To: Mon Mar 23 13:14:36 CET 2020]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    94778886 f4ca92c2]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 86 EE 6C 03 20 76 E5 0C   C7 1D E5 44 60 C0 D0 40  ..l. v.....D`..@
0010: 02 96 EE 05 39 31 E8 5A   FE F4 72 7B 9B CC E7 0F  ....91.Z..r.....
0020: 97 E6 41 7E EC E3 65 C5   A2 B0 41 61 93 B4 48 EE  ..A...e...Aa..H.
0030: DE 44 76 94 C1 48 E4 05   96 C2 0A 9B 1C 94 1B 85  .Dv..H..........
0040: 96 9F F3 00 D3 AC B7 95   C5 2C D5 ED 52 FA D7 79  .........,..R..y
0050: A1 10 BB CB A4 BD 30 08   51 71 50 EE DC 60 88 AD  ......0.QqP..`..
0060: 31 6E 88 D9 97 F3 8B 5B   01 B3 80 B2 B2 06 62 FB  1n.....[......b.
0070: DE A4 74 87 D9 2A 2B 2F   AF 31 22 97 4A F6 B8 9F  ..t..*+/.1".J...

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net, OU=enxi.norrisdata.net, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 105158323961649143261675059370957210288137897982882368398075567460896421730512351351129218695072925445303830065152794594929017968110838209795249871435238567060656353603426816451022832577131638028495007888967083020723809918589055189033188525472465535607293377867184162059586888049098196531889988723950292830313
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Mar 26 11:37:00 CET 2010,
               To: Mon Mar 23 11:37:00 CET 2020]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    02]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 3A F3 91 84 EA B1 CF 28   7B 52 EC 50 34 56 CB A5  :......(.R.P4V..
0010: 22 B2 3C 62 9B 8C 45 30   BE 89 C6 8C D5 CD D0 4C  ".<b..E0.......L
0020: 0A 92 3C AB C6 72 5C 7E   A4 4B 12 B5 3D 90 6F D1  ..<..r\..K..=.o.
0030: 8D 23 8F FE 46 9E D5 15   BA 8D 32 12 79 86 D8 42  .#..F.....2.y..B
0040: A9 AF 95 3A 58 D6 F0 1C   C9 44 B7 AB 78 F8 0E 16  ...:X....D..x...
0050: E5 B1 30 29 56 D5 C1 4F   06 D2 5C 9B 7F 61 22 7D  ..0)V..O..\..a".
0060: 6C EB C5 7C 02 8B D4 3B   3B 66 20 55 72 2D 1B F1  l......;;f Ur-..
0070: 3A 28 3F 10 80 BC 9F 46   DA 0E 8F DC 53 0E 0B 85  :(?....F....S...

]
http-8080-Processor25, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 14
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, Type-64, 
Cert Authorities:
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: ypsilonclient
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 103786554737956184369138386227517475430156404603922533481712260490997247291004352385079204978431207687092828117962473600295977103686791448953158848873575487907656378655168840104433047747570602454550203304683174555325033654946526304210710782190667961616217273402229863778090825217190222869236148684215668636483
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Mar 26 13:14:36 CET 2010,
               To: Mon Mar 23 13:14:36 CET 2020]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=aw@ypsilon.net, CN=enxi.norrisdata.net-ca, OU=Certificate Authority, O=ypsilon.net ag, L=Frankfurt, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    94778886 f4ca92c2]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 86 EE 6C 03 20 76 E5 0C   C7 1D E5 44 60 C0 D0 40  ..l. v.....D`..@
0010: 02 96 EE 05 39 31 E8 5A   FE F4 72 7B 9B CC E7 0F  ....91.Z..r.....
0020: 97 E6 41 7E EC E3 65 C5   A2 B0 41 61 93 B4 48 EE  ..A...e...Aa..H.
0030: DE 44 76 94 C1 48 E4 05   96 C2 0A 9B 1C 94 1B 85  .Dv..H..........
0040: 96 9F F3 00 D3 AC B7 95   C5 2C D5 ED 52 FA D7 79  .........,..R..y
0050: A1 10 BB CB A4 BD 30 08   51 71 50 EE DC 60 88 AD  ......0.QqP..`..
0060: 31 6E 88 D9 97 F3 8B 5B   01 B3 80 B2 B2 06 62 FB  1n.....[......b.
0070: DE A4 74 87 D9 2A 2B 2F   AF 31 22 97 4A F6 B8 9F  ..t..*+/.1".J...

]
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
Random Secret:  { 3, 1, 110, 20, 216, 88, 174, 234, 11, 164, 154, 148, 54, 171, 55, 181, 52, 238, 214, 252, 168, 169, 18, 121, 177, 216, 220, 143, 238, 36, 200, 90, 23, 216, 108, 223, 141, 204, 89, 1, 87, 183, 19, 114, 250, 78, 84, 76 }
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 833
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 6E 14 D8 58 AE EA   0B A4 9A 94 36 AB 37 B5  ..n..X......6.7.
0010: 34 EE D6 FC A8 A9 12 79   B1 D8 DC 8F EE 24 C8 5A  4......y.....$.Z
0020: 17 D8 6C DF 8D CC 59 01   57 B7 13 72 FA 4E 54 4C  ..l...Y.W..r.NTL
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 4D 46 DC 07 E9 20 8A 6A   1F EB AE 3E 35 FC 9B FF  MF... .j...>5...
0010: F8 2B FF 3A 63 46 E8 11   DC 62 2A 28 65 9D 1A 71  .+.:cF...b*(e..q
Server Nonce:
0000: 4D 46 DC 07 C9 F1 63 26   8C 00 84 14 E7 BA A5 F3  MF....c&........
0010: B2 8F 92 AC 6C A1 7E 4A   46 38 8A A5 27 63 FE AD  ....l..JF8..'c..
Master Secret:
0000: DE 21 44 E2 E9 3B E8 1E   EE 64 D3 44 B2 41 D6 F8  .!D..;...d.D.A..
0010: 06 67 95 7B 4C 8C D3 DB   AC C4 85 1E 35 67 30 1A  .g..L.......5g0.
0020: 36 F2 15 EE 5E 1D 3F 67   35 74 4F 0B 0B EE 02 92  6...^.?g5tO.....
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 9E AF AB 0F D1 71 21 ED   0B B5 BB 65 12 F2 F9 0A  .....q!....e....
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: BD 17 61 C4 3F FE 61 8D   85 EF 5A E9 2D 8E 06 CD  ..a.?.a...Z.-...
Client write key:
0000: C0 0D 6C 01 63 74 1D E6   53 04 92 BC 6D 12 A6 8F  ..l.ct..S...m...
Server write key:
0000: 32 B4 99 5C 37 A2 83 67   78 09 95 55 C8 63 72 6F  2..\7..gx..U.cro
... no IV for cipher
*** CertificateVerify
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 134
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 47, 74, 83, 184, 225, 220, 176, 197, 212, 45, 72, 182 }
***
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
http-8080-Processor25, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
http-8080-Processor25, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-8080-Processor25, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
http-8080-Processor25, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
http-8080-Processor25, called closeSocket()
http-8080-Processor25, called close()
http-8080-Processor25, called closeInternal(true)
http-8080-Processor25, called close()
http-8080-Processor25, called closeInternal(true)
http-8080-Processor25, called close()
http-8080-Processor25, called closeInternal(true)
```

Why does my connection keep resetting and how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I wish we had some server-side logs to see what it doesn't like. My guess is that is doesn't like your client certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not control the server (I'm not even sure the server is Java). Regarding the client certificate, this is what I did to import it (starting from PEM files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

I did this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -outform der -in clientkey.pem -out clientkey.der
```

But I didn't do this:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in clientkey.pem -out clientkey.cer
```

Both files need to be imported into keystore through Java, not keytool. I was importing only the clientkey.der.

Turns out you have to separately import client key and server certificate in keystore; I wasn't aware that converting .pem to .der didn't export attached server certificate as well.

Comment: By the way, "No IV for cipher" is obviously not an error, since this message is displayed in debug even after the problem was fixed.

Comment: Do you recall the command you used to create clientkey.pem? Every time I try, I keep getting "unable to load key".

Comment: Unfortunately no, the .pem file was provided to me by the service I was connecting to. :(

Answer (score 1):

'Connection reset' usually means you have written to a connection which has already been closed by the other end. There are numerous other causes but this is the most likely. In this case it appears you are in the middle of the SSL handshake. Possibly you need to disable SSLv2ClientHello in the enabled protocols.

Comment: How do I disable it? I tried upgrading to newer Java which supports sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation and sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages properties (I'm on 1.5.0_06 because of dependencies which don't support higher revisions), and tried all possible combinations, but all I got was decrypt_error or "Software caused connection abort: recv failed" (I can post debug again in another question.)

Comment: It looks to me like the peers cleanly negotiate to TLS 1.0 without incident.